# How do you calculate the Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error in h2o?

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

As mentioned, how to calculate that with a h2o model, what's the most optimum way to do this with a large volume of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

h2o doesn't currently have RMSLE implemented (only RMSE), but it makes sense to add. Here is the [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3218) where you can track the progress.

Update: Support has been added to implement RMSE from version 3.10.0.5.

Comment: Thanks for the ticket Lauren, seeing as you are a member of 0xdata, any idea when the feature will be implemented ?

Comment: @Lauren Do you mean RMSLE added from version 3.10.0.5?